# What is the "right" way to add libraries on Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm a using Netbeans 8.1 to code in Java, when I want to add an external library (such as XStream, JDateChooser, etc) I find the `.jar` online and I add it to my project through the right clicking in `Libraries --> add JAR/Folder`.

[image: Screenshot add jar]

After this I write my code and everything works fine until I finish my project and I want to export it into a `.jar` with `Clean and Build`

[image: Screenshot Clean and Build]

I think this maybe because I give an absolute path to the libaray instead of a relative one but I'm not sure.

*PS: The library that I'm having trouble with is `XStream 1.4.7`*

Comment: Providing absolute path to `.jar` file reference is not a good idea, instead use relative path while selecting/adding `.jar` file reference to your project.

Answer (score 1):

All the libraries included should pack in a `jar` file after build. The simplest approach is to click right on your project, select `Properties` and `The project properties`. In the new window opened find `Categories` and `Libraries`. The in the right side you may see the button `Add library/JAR`. Probably it's the same way.

Also you can create a Maven project and import all the libraries through dependencies.